# How do I find out what the Series number is on my Briggs and Stratton Engine?

Tags: small-engine, briggs-stratton

How do I find out what the Series number is on my Briggs and Stratton Engine?

I have found, and do know the model, type, and code of my engine, but I am looking for the Series number.

When I'm looking for a tune-up kit for my Briggs and Stratton engine, the tune-up kit packages list the Series numbers for the engines that they fit.  However, there is nothing on my engine (model, type, or code) that matches this series number, and I can't find any cross-reference charts to match it up.

I want to be able to find the correct tune-up kit without having to ask my dealer to look it up.  Also it's just annoying that the tune-up kit's matching models are displayed so prominently as a reference, but that information is no where to be found.

I called my dealer, and they were no help.  He said, "Everything we do is based on model, type, and code."

**Examples:**

[Here's a tune-up kit](https://www.briggsandstratton.com/us/en/shop/parts-and-accessories/tune-up-kits/5140web-tune-up-kit).  The description shows exactly what I mean when it lists the Series numbers in this line: "*This Briggs & Stratton Genuine Tune-Up Kit is designed exclusively for 625e, 675ex, 725ex Series™, 625-675 Series™ and Quantum™ 3.5-6.75 gross HP‡ push mower engines*"

Here's the information I have:

```
DOM NOV 2010
128T02-3124-B1
```

My understanding is that this means:

- Model: `128T02`
- Type: `3124`
- Code: `B1`

Comment: So can you find the plate on the engine that lists the Model and Type?  Does [this](https://www.briggsandstratton.com/us/en/shop/parts-and-accessories/locate-model-number) help?

Comment: @JPhi1618: yes, I do know the model, type, and code.  I updated my question to make this more clear.  Thanks

Comment: You might want to add your model number and an example of the Quantum series number so people know exactly what you're trying to correlate.  I know you want the _source_ for matching the two, but I think real data will help.

Comment: good idea @JPhi1618.  I added that to the question.

Comment: The "Code" seems to be a `B1` rather than an eight, but that doesn't really help you.  Interesting that the series number is such a closely guarded secret, lol.

Comment: Indeed @JPhi1618 It's top secret.  They're doing their best to provide their customers with the information.  It's a real surprise they've lasted on the market this long.  #Winning

Answer (score 4):

I was able to do it by doing a model and type search for manuals on the Briggs & Stratton site:

http://www.briggsandstratton.com/us/en/support/manuals/engine

On that page, enter the model and type of your engine, and the cover of the resulting operators manual has the series numbers that match. There are 3 or 4 series listed for your model and type. But, they all look different enough that a search on the Briggs and Stratton site should get you pics of each individual series type (the manual does not identify each one, just shows pics and lists all the covered series) and from that find the one that looks like yours.

Basically, the manual cover gets you a short list of series numbers and your engine belongs to one of them. Then use the pics to narrow it down to the correct series.

I'm a little gob smacked that it took this to find out what series the model and type belong to. Suddenly I'm very happy that my snow blower has a Tecumseh engine. lol

Hope that helps!

Comment: You win the prize cdunn.  This question has gone unanswered by the site for too long.  Your one in a million...well, actually your one in thousands.  Congrats and thanks for the contribution.  Welcome to SE.  Hope to see more of you.

Comment: The search on the briggs and stratton site doesn't bring up pictures or really any results.

Comment: True, you can't do the search on the site itself, use google to search for the series name and you get results like the following:  http://www.briggsandstratton.com/us/en/engines/push-mower-engines/675ex-series

Comment: Thank you for your kind words @DucatiKiller  I'm a software engineer but I'm rediscovering my inner grease monkey. Between cars, small engines, and even guns, the intricacies and innovations in mechanical design make me wonder if I shouldn't have been a mechanical engineer instead of software / electrical. lol  I love the knowledge, theory, practical tips and tricks that this site provides, it's awesome! I hope to be a part of it for a long time.

Comment: Here's another link to the 675ex series that gives a better image and more info about the models in the series:   http://www.briggsandstratton.com/eu/en/engines/lawn-mower-engines/675ex-series   It's for the EU zone and not North America, but it may point in the right direction. Anyway, bottom line, the search function on the site itself kind of stinks and is geared to the model number only. A general Google search for the series name from the manual cover is what gets you to the info you need @Ballpark  I hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

The series is typically on a decal on the engine or on the Operators Manuel
You're best bet for verifying a maintenance kit is to get the Model Type and Trim number from the engine and compare the air filter part number on the illustrated parts list on the Briggs and Stratton site. Or, chat a B and S agent and they can find the info for you.